# StartCoroutine does not get called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour {

     public GameObject deathEffect;
     public float health = 4f;
     public static int EnemiesAlive = 0;
     public int loadToScene;

     void Start ()
     {
         EnemiesAlive++;
     }

     void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D colInfo)
     {
         if (colInfo.relativeVelocity.magnitude > health)
         {
             Die();
         }
     }

     void Die ()
     {
         Instantiate(deathEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

         EnemiesAlive--;

         if (EnemiesAlive <= 0)
         {
             Debug.Log ("LEVEL WON!");
             StartCoroutine (delay()); //delay here

             loadToScene = 1;
             SceneManager.LoadScene (loadToScene);
         }
         Destroy(gameObject);
     }

     IEnumerator delay ()
     {
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
         Debug.Log ("Coroutine started?");
     }
}
```

The code is about changing scene when the number of enemies is less than or equal to zero. I would like to add a delay before changing scene, given the condition "EnemiesAlive <= 0" is fulfilled. I use StartCoroutine, but for some reason I don't know, StartCoroutine is not called and the scene changed immediately without delay. Why is that?

[image]

"Debug.Log ("LEVEL WON!");" is read but "Debug.Log ("Coroutine started?");" did not run.

Comment: You should not put tags in titles. The tag system on the site is plenty enough to show what platform you are working on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not waiting for `delay()` to finish before you call `SceneManager.LoadScene (loadToScene);`. When you call `SceneManager.LoadScene (loadToScene);` that stops all Coroutines that are waiting to run so the routine is stopped before the two seconds are up.

Try putting the log before the `WaitForSeconds` and I *think* you will get the output before the scene changes.

If you want your `Die` code to wait two seconds you need to make Die also return a IEnumerable and yield for the wait then call `Die` with `StartCoroutine`.

```
 void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D colInfo)
 {
     if (colInfo.relativeVelocity.magnitude > health)
     {
         StartCoroutine(Die());
     }
 }

 IEnumerator Die ()
 {
     Instantiate(deathEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

     EnemiesAlive--;

     if (EnemiesAlive <= 0)
     {
         Debug.Log ("LEVEL WON!");
         yield return StartCoroutine (delay()); //delay here

         loadToScene = 1;
         SceneManager.LoadScene (loadToScene);
     }
     Destroy(gameObject);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I use other method without changing the die() method into IEnumerator? I have try using Invoke() before changing the scene but it is also not called. Is it correct to put Invoke() between the log and SceneManager?